# Scala list of list String find distinct elements

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Hi my scala list contains following elements

```
val myList = List(List("A","B","C","E"),List("A","A1","B1","C","E"),List("P","E","L","A"))
```

now I want to find out distinct elements from above list so my final list will be

```
val finalList = List ("A","E")
```

How this find out in scala ?

Comment: I wouldn't call that "distinct elements". You mean elements appearing in every list.

Comment: @Paul you right I want to find common element in every list but by typo mistake it inserted distinct

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Find intersection between all inner lists:

```
myList.reduceLeft(_.intersect(_))  // List[String] = List(A, E)
```

Comment: It work fine but, can you explain some little bit how this reduceLeft solve my problem or can I used reduceRight ?

Comment: @yogesh For your question there is no difference between `reduceLeft` and `reduceRight`. First iteration you find intersection between 1st and 2nd elements of list. Next iteration you find intersection between  previous result and next element. And so on and so forth.

Comment: reduceLeft (or reduceRight) applies a binary function typed A => A => A to the underlying Traversable, starting with the first element. E.g. List(1,2,3,4).reduceLeft(_ + _) == List(1+2,3,4).reduceLeft(...) == List(1+2+3,4).reduceLeft(...) == List(1+2+3+4). ReduceRight just goes the other way around.